# arrange 2 array on ascending order - C programming

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I got stuck when I am trying to arrange 2 arrays in ascending way.
for example, I have:

```
X[] = {4,2,8,2}
Y[] = {12,12,6,12}
```

I would like to arrange X[] in ascending order, but if i change a value place on the array, the same value on Y[] array will change also to the same place.

result:

```
X[] = {8,4,2,2}
Y[] = {6,12,12,12}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where's your code!? Show your code and we try to understand where's the problem(s).

Comment: @David  Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: _ascending order_ --> descending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You juste have to, when sorting, moving 2 arrays element at the same time

Here is an exemple with Bubble sort: (with `n` the length of your array)

```
for(int last=0; last<n; last++)
{
    for(int new=0; new<n-1; new++)
    {
        if(X[new]>X[new+1])
        {
            int temp = X[new+1];
            X[new+1] = X[new];
            X[new] = temp;

            temp = Y[new+1];
            Y[new+1] = Y[new];
            Y[new] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Just like this (so duplicated in the loop where moving the array's elements)

Comment: Thanks alot, clean and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an arbitrary sort function. For instance bubble sort. Modify the function so that the same operations are being made to both.

```
void swap(long *a, long *b)
{
  int t=*a;
  *a=*b;
  *b=t;
}

void bubble_sort(long list[], long n, long extra[])
{
  long c, d, t;

  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
      if (list[d] > list[d+1])
      {
        swap(list[d], list[d+1]);
        swap(extra[d], extra[d+1]);
      }
}
```